# File accept issue in safari for .pdf

Tags: html

I am try to upload only image and pdf file. it's work fine in chrome and firefox but in safari(Version 6.0.5) not accepting .pdf file(it accept only image files) here I attach sample code..

input type=file accept=image/png,.pdf

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is sample code???

Comment: <input type='file' accept='image/png,.pdf'>

Comment: for PDF use this application/pdf

Comment: Ya it's working thank you. I have doubt in chrome and FF .pdf support but in safari not working why?

Comment: In FireFox its shows all the file like .csv and other accept not working